# Laravel Query Builder Search (match against)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to write this query in Laravel

```
select *, MATCH(hobbies)AGAINST('soccer') from users where MATCH(hobbies)AGAINST('soccer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

I have looked in the documentation on query builder but didn't find anything on full-text search.

Please help.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Laravel doesn't have things this specific built in, you'll need to create a [raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries) for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Samsquanch he pointed me in the right direction.
Here is how I got it done.

```php
$my_query = "select *, MATCH (name) AGAINST (?) from users 
    where MATCH (hobbies) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 10 OFFSET ?"

$hobbies = DB::select($my_query, array($search_term, $search_term, (($page-1)*10)));
```

Comment: Just be careful with SQL injection in the $search_term

Comment: @DimitriMostrey you cannot sql inject a prepared statement. Because parameter values are transmitted later using a different protocol. They don’t even need to be escaped. If the original statement template is not derived from an external input sql injection cannot occur.

Answer (score 10):

```
User::selectRaw("*, MATCH(hobbies)AGAINST('soccer')")
    ->whereRaw("MATCH(hobbies)AGAINST('soccer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->limit(10);
```

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays, Laravel supports fullTextSearch in Query builder. You can have a look here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#full-text-where-clauses.

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.