# Laravel - search with multiple keywords against multiple columns with the search result to be ordered in relevance

Tags: mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, search, laravel-scout

I am trying to implement a search in Laravel. it will have a search bar where 3 keywords will be given as input. There are 2 columns namely `meta_name` and `meta_description` in the database against which the search will be made. Suppose the search words are `word1 word2 word3`. Order of the search words matters. The rule is: rows that have both the 3 words in the 2 mentioned columns i.e., `meta_name` and `meta_description` will be shown in the first place. Then rows containing **only** `word1 word2` (**note that** I mean **only the first 2 words**) in the mentioned columns will come in the second place. After that rows containing only `word1` in the mentioned 2 columns will come in the 3rd place. When I say rows contain words such as`word1 word2`, it means `word1` and `word2` can be present in any or both of the 2 columns i.e., `meta_name` and `meta_description`. If a row is already shown , then it will not reappear in search results.

The search results will be shown in a load-on-scroll manner just like Facebook. It means whenever we go to the bottom of the page by scrolling downward, new results will be loaded i.e., appended to the previous results. When there is no data, a message will be shown that no more data is available .

To accomplish the purpose, I am following a tutorial from [here](https://makitweb.com/load-content-on-page-scroll-in-laravel/). They have the source code in Github [here](https://github.com/makitweb/How-to-Load-content-on-page-scroll-in-Laravel-9).

The technique is, on page scroll, it is calculated whether the bottom of the page is reached. If so, then an ajax call is made which sends how many results have already been showed. Then in the controller (You will find it in `getPosts` method of the `PostsController` in the source code), the following code is executed :

```
$start = $request->get('start');//how many results have already been shown

$records = Post::select('*')
                ->skip($start)
                ->take($this->rowperpage) // $this->rowperpage= 4 e.g.
                ->get();
```

and the corresponding results are sent as ajax response to be appended to the already shown search results.

In my case, the challenge remains in finding the database rows in the appropriate order. Similar questions are out there in this site but that does not exactly address my issues. One such question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657297/how-to-get-and-order-the-most-relevant-entries-from-the-database-with-multiple-k). Taking help from there, I tried to solve the problem in the following way though it did not serve the purpose:

```
$posts = Posts::where([
    ['meta_name', 'Like', '%word1%'],
    ['meta_name', 'Like', '%word2%'],
    ['meta_name', 'Like', '%word3%'],
    ['meta_description', 'Like', '%word1%'],
    ['meta_description', 'Like', '%word2%'],
    ['meta_description', 'Like', '%word3%'],
    
])->get();
```

But **obviously** , it gets me  nowhere. The above query is only for matching all three words in the columns `meta_name` and `meta_description`.

You can just clone the Github repo I gave above to run the Laravel code in your  system. And for generating demo data , you can use the Laravel faker library. A tutorial on faker from [here](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-8-generate-fake-data-using-faker-example) or any other place will be helpful.

How to solve the problem then?

Comment: Look into full text search from mysql. That is what you need.

Comment: @marius-ciclistu, is that available in Laravel?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout with Elastic search but I think it should work without it  using raw match sql.

Comment: @marius-ciclistu, any sample code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488926/laravel-query-builder-search-match-against    your 2 columns should have index of type full text search and your schema to be innodb.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb

Comment: @marius-ciclistu, how to maintain the order of the search results as I said in OP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254096/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-marius-ciclistu).

Comment: Read the documentation of full text search in mysql. It has some signs . For example + means all words. Default is with or but I think it is ordering the results close to what you want.

Comment: try separate queries for each set of words and merge them afterwards

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, can I try by just using MYSQL ? Can you write the first 2 queries ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this has another method. But this is what I thought of it

```
$word1 = 'word1';
$word2 = 'word2';
$word3 = 'word3';

$all = DB::table('posts')
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word2}%")
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word3}%")
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($word1, $word2, $word3) {
        $query->where('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
              ->where('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word2}%")
              ->where('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word3}%");
    });

$twoWords = DB::table('posts')
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word2}%")
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($word1, $word2) {
        $query->where('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
              ->where('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word2}%");
    })
    ->whereNotIn('id', $all->pluck('id'));

$oneWord = DB::table('posts')
    ->where('meta_name', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
    ->orWhere('meta_description', 'like', "%{$word1}%")
    ->whereNotIn('id', $all->pluck('id'))
    ->whereNotIn('id', $twoWords->pluck('id'));
```

and finally `union` all

```
$posts = $all->union($twoWords)->union($oneWord)->get(); // check this first
# or
$posts = $all->union($twoWords)->union($oneWord)->skip($start)->take($this->rowperpage)->get();
```